# gzip vs http speed on industrial server

Tags: optimization, proxy, compression, amazon-ec2

Im writing a proxy app that is going to be deployed on Amazon EC2. Which of these options would be faster, and generally good practice for my application?

Request compressed > uncompress > proxify / modify html > compress > send compressed

or

Request uncompressed > proxify / modify html > send uncompressed

I know compressed is generally better, but this is different because we have to decompress AND recompress AND Amazon EC2 has blazing fast internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compression is more of an optimization for the client than for the server so Amazon's speed is less relevant, that said, the only downside of compression would be if it takes much more time, but I don't that would be an issue.

Comment: What about

Request uncompressed > proxify / modify html > compress > send compressed?

Comment: That would be the most intuitive thing to do (if the server -> amazon tube is very wide), but really I doubt you can measure any difference unless the site hast tons of traffic.